# how to read code part of technical book on kobo

Tags: epub, kobo, css

I have many technical ebooks with coding examples but it's unreadable because there's no scrollbar and many lines are longer than my ebook screen.

I have tried to change it in an open ebook by adding that code below in pre balise :

```
style="overflow:auto;overflow-scroll=true; overflow-y:hidden; word-wrap:normal;"
```

I see a scrolling bar on my webbrowser(firefox), I see that scrolling bar in calibre reader but not on my kobo?

How could I read code on my kobo?

here an exemple of ebooks containing code :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/epub/spring-boot-reference.epub

That ebook is free but it's the same for expensive ebooks.

regards,