# How to wrap long lines inside 'pre code' environments, for Kobo

Tags: kobo, css, formatting

I am trying to build an ebook from a programming tutorial (markdown):

it contains many code blocks with comments; the comment lines are too long for the width of my Kobo H2O v2 reader, so I can't read the end...

I tried adding a [CSS style](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/EPUB#General) for wrapping:

```
<style>pre code { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }</style>
```

- It makes no difference to the Kobo default reader (nickel)...
- However, the `ebook-viewer` command from calibre detects it and wraps them (instead of creating an horizontal scroll bar).
- Also, inside Koreader, all exceeding lines are wrapped, no matter what CSS I add.

*How do I make the default Kobo reader automatically wrap `pre` lines, without changing the source markdown?*

Here is a [similar unanswered question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7503/19485).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct CSS to include, which is dependent from the way [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) produces the html:

```
<style>pre > code.sourceCode { white-space: pre-wrap !important; }</style>
```

Comment: very interesting; by the way it looks like the Amazon supported CSS does NOT include the white-space pre-wrap attribute. https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GB5GDY7WAJDN9GFK

Occasionally this Kindle reference is wrong though. I'd be very curious whether it works on Kindle devices or the Kindle app.